# "Unpermitted parameter:" error in Two Many-To-Many association with nested attributes added to whitelist already

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, nested-attributes, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm taking my first steps "on rails". I looked up several questions on stackoverflow and used google A LOT, but still I can't seem to solve my problem.

I´m trying to write a rails app that lets you manage a list of movies, and a list of actors. Movies can have multiple actors (and hence an actor can star in multiple movies).I have two models `Movie` and `Actor` as well as the joint `ActorsMovie` model. As you can see, I want to establish a Two Many-To-Many relationship.

**Please find the relevant files here:**
https://gist.github.com/ecksma/f09d2a6ec631e46eafe9

Even though I added `params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :year, actors_attributes:[:actor_id,:name] )` to `movies_controller`, I get an `Unpermitted parameter: actors` error when I try to create a new movie with an actor.

**Command line output**
https://gist.github.com/ecksma/f09d2a6ec631e46eafe9#file-command_line_output

I have the same problem when I try to create a new actor with movies. The actor is created but I get `Unpermitted parameter: movies`, although I added `params.require(:actor).permit(:name, movies_attributes:[:title,:year,:movie_id])` to `actors_controller`.

Forms and basic CRUD seems to work, except that I can't seem to hook up movies with actors and vice versa.

Any suggestions on what I´m doing wrong?

Comment: can you post the entire controller and the form please? it seems you have a wrong field there

Comment: If you follow this link [Form,Controller,Models etc](https://gist.github.com/ecksma/f09d2a6ec631e46eafe9), you should find all relevant files in a gist (such as the entire controller). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :actors` in `Movie` model?

Comment: I just tried and it works. Thank you so much! That was really helpful. Nonetheless there is a strange behaviour when editing movies. Everytime I add an actor to an existing movie, the actor that was initially added with the movie gets listed twice afterwards.

Comment: You need to permit "id" in "actors_attributes". When you do MyModel.update_attributes(params) it checks for "id". If "id" is present record gets updated else new record is created.

Comment: You are great, that really helped me out! Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't. It says once I earned 15 reputation my votes will be displayed publicly. I don't have that, yet. :/